# Login does not work in Ionic View App

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic-view

There are some issues about Ionic View App BUT none like mine. I was hoping that someone could help me out.

The issue is that I can't login to my app while using Ionic View on my iPhone.

I am under the impression that Ionic View is ONLY to preview static apps? My login code hits a development server url and it works fine on the emulators, browser and both iOs and Android devices.

When I run the `ionic upload` command in my terminal everything goes well and I can view the login screen on my iPhone for the app BUT it does not accept my login credentials or any.

Why is this and what can I do?

The reason I don't have any code to show is because I am not getting errors and the login on my app works fine everywhere else.

Any ideas?

Comment: just the login or all the http requests ?? i think your problem is with the whitelist plugin please add it and try again https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Hey Anas! I have the whitelist plugin installed.. No idea why this is happening still.. My login is an http request to my users API

Comment: Hello Shotbyable, I have the same problem, did you found any solution? thanks

Comment: @miholzi I actually never got this to work. I ended up just having to set up our servers haha.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might still have this issue the problem is most likely the ionic view app. Native code tends to not work in the view app and most be ran as native  (apk or ipa)